# Minikube flag not found

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a problem with minikube
when I want to create deployment manifest files, I receive an error
when I write this code:
`minikube kubectl create -f .`
I got this Error:

Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.

but not only this, I try to write another command but again same error happening

`minikube kubectl delete daemonsets,replicasets,services,deployments,pods,rc,pvc --all` 
Error: unknown flag: --all
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.

please help me.
thanks

Comment: Just use `kubectl` without the `minikube` wrapper, or include a `--` after `minikube kubectl`.  See the [Minikube kubectl documentation page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, --all is not a valid flag. Valid flag is --all-namespaces or just -A.

However, "kubectl delete" does not take -A as it needs the resource name for deletion.

To accomplish what you are trying to do you will have to write a loop to delete the objects 1 by one using

```
kubectl get daemonsets,replicasets,services,deployments,pods,rc,pvc -A --no-headers | while read line; do 
    namespace=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    resource=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    kubectl delete ${resource} -n ${namespace}
done
```

**Execution - BE extremely careful with this as it will delete all queried resources in all namespaces including those in kube-system namespace**:

```
controlplane $ kubectl get daemonsets,replicasets,services,deployments,pods,rc,pvc -A --no-headers | while read line; do 
>     namespace=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
>     resource=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
>     kubectl delete ${resource} -n ${namespace}
> done
daemonset.extensions "kube-keepalived-vip" deleted
daemonset.extensions "kube-proxy" deleted
daemonset.extensions "weave-net" deleted
replicaset.extensions "coredns-fb8b8dccf" deleted
replicaset.extensions "katacoda-cloud-provider-d5cb9d656" deleted
service "kubernetes" deleted
service "kube-dns" deleted
deployment.extensions "coredns" deleted
deployment.extensions "katacoda-cloud-provider" deleted
```